# Best practice for to count text line

Tags: c#, filesystemwatcher, .net-4.5

I would to know how I can read, for example, line from 10 to 12, in a log file, starting from upper of file, without having the message that the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. Thanks a lot

Comment: try opening the file for 'read-only' it may help, but it ultimately depends on how the other process has the file opened

Comment: If the other process has a read lock you can open it in read mode as well. Otherwise you'll get this exception. Your body and title have nothing to do with eachother though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  If another process has a lock on the file, you can't access it.

Comment: @GianniGiordano Not if another process has locked the file.  You can do that if no other process has a lock on the file.

Comment: You can, if you enable the Volume Shadow Service then use a library like AlphaFS to read a snapshot of the file. That's how backup programs are able to deal with open files

Comment: May you explain better please?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Were you to try you'd have no idea what you could get.  Trying to read through a file that someone else is in the process of writing to could result in all sorts of problems, such as garbage data.

Comment: @GianniGiordano What else is there to explain.  If another process has locked the file then you can't read from it.  The whole point of locking a file is to actively prevent anyone else from reading it.

Comment: Almost true - not garbage, just incomplete data. Log files though only append lines so the data is correct up to the last entry

Comment: Volume Shadow Copy what it does is easy to explain as when you open the file it create a copy in temp and open that on so the original file stays untouched/not locked.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos But of course you can't know whether or not you're on the last entry.  And that's assuming that whatever has taken a write lock out on the file is only ever appending.  They might, they might not.  Unless you were the one that wrote it, you can't necessarily be sure.

Comment: Sometimes it's also possible to read files that have been opened as Share Read.

Comment: @Servy that's OK for log files. In fact, it's almost standard practice in Linux systems to check the tail of log files for the latest entries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And if that were the case, then he wouldn't be getting this error.

Comment: I try to explain better my scenario so you understand more: with FileSystemWatcher I want to monitor a file and when the external program updates it, I would like to retrieve the rows that have been added.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, but they don't actively violate file locks when doing so.  Checking the log file *when nobody else has it locked for writing* is of course fine.

Comment: @GianniGiordano And that's fine, but you won't be able to do it if another process has the file locked for writing.

Comment: so I'll have to use a copy of the file in the temp path ... I understand you correctly?

Comment: @GianniGiordano How do you intend to get a copy of the file if it's locked by another process?

Comment: You can't do that either. Copying implies opening the file to read its contents. You'll have to retry until the file is released. Also note that FSW can raise a lot of change events for the same file but it won't raise a Change event. You need to wait until it quiets down before retrying.

Comment: I apologize are inexperienced ... may I have an example of how to copy a locked file from another program please?

Comment: *YOU CAN'T**. That's the point of the entire conversation. Copying means you open the file, read the contents and write them to another file. Whether your code does it block by block, or the OS does it in response to a File.Copy command is the same.

Comment: May I might have a flow of operations to be performed?